# AngularJS - ng-cloak on button not working (flicker still exists) in Chromium - ng-cloak doesn't even get added to the CSS for some reason

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ng-hide, ngcloak

This is my HTML (amongst other things):

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary ng-cloak" ng-click="ctrl.add(ctrl.userProfile.username)" ng-hide="ctrl.userProfile.added">Add</button>
```

The HTML above is extending this HTML page:

```
<html ng-app="UserPageApp">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrapCSS/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/base.css">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="js/base.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrapJS/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <base href="/">
    </head>
```

This is my base.css (amongst a few other things):

```
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
  display: none !important;
}
```

The problem is, when the page loads, the "Add" button appears and then disappears after a second (even when ng-hide evaluates to True. Note: This is what I mean by the 'flicker'). Is there a way for me to not allow the button to show up at all if ng-hide evaluates to True?

Edit: When I change `class="btn btn-primary ng-cloak"` to `class="btn btn-primary ng-cloaks"` and make this my CSS:

```
/* add ng-cloaks */
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak, .ng-cloaks {
  display: none !important;
}
```

then it successfully does not display the button. It seems as if some JS is removing ng-cloak on load?

Edit 2: I removed ng-hide from my button and turns out that the ng-cloak class doesn't even get added to the button (I used "inspect element" in Chromium and saw that the ng-cloak CSS is not even being applied and the class ng-cloak does not appear on the buttons lass). So it seems as if AngularJS is removing the ng-cloak class for some reason (and like I mentioned earlier, when I change it to .ng-cloaks, it works perfectly fine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the error. Although I didn't mention it in my post, `ctrl.userProfile.added` didn't exist initially (in my user.js file, all I had was `self.userProfile = []` initially). I then did a get request and loaded `self.userProfile` which then became `self.userProfile = {'added': true}`. So I guess AngularJS was displaying the button because `self.userProfile.watching` was originally undefined.